# Is there a trick overriding a function without a constructor in python?

Tags: python, class, overriding, parent-child

I have a problem while overrding functions from Parent Class to Child Class...

Is there a trick overriding a function without a constructor?

```py
class Vehicle:
    def get_wheels(self):
        return -1

class Jeep(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Motorcycle(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

jeep = Jeep()
print("Jeep has", jeep.get_wheels(), "wheels")

motorcycle = Motorcycle()
print("Motorcycle has", motorcycle.get_wheels(), "wheels")
```

expected output should be

```
Jeep has 4 wheels
Motorcycle has 2 wheels
```

the parent class should only have the function no other than anything

Comment: Where do you tell it a Jeep has 4 wheels? Why do you expect that output when the number 4 is nowhere in your code?

Comment: Since the subclasses don't override `get_wheels` they get the super class' version which just returns -1. If you put `def get_wheels(self): return 4` in `Jeep`, you'd get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing to more accurate terminology, its okay to subclass a class without an initializer. In fact, `object` has an `__init__` and `Vehicle` implicitly inherits from `object` so, its there.

Its okay for a subclass to call `super().__init__()` even if the superclass doesn't have an `__init__()`. It ends up calling `object.__init__()`. Its not necessary, but future proofs code in case somebody adds to the super class init later. In your case however, your sublcass `__init__`'s don't do anything so they don't need to be there.

Your problem is that you don't override anything that will change the wheel count, so your subclasses call the super's method which returns -1. Instead you could

```
class Vehicle:
    def get_wheels(self):
        return -1

class Jeep(Vehicle):
    # there is no need to write an init that just calls the super's
    # init. That would happen autotmatically without this override
    #def __init__(self):
    #    super().__init__()

    # but you should override the thing you want to be different
    def get_wheels(self):
        return 4

class Motorcycle(Vehicle):
    #def __init__(self):
    #    super().__init__()
    def get_wheels(self):
        return 2

jeep = Jeep()
print("Jeep has", jeep.get_wheels(), "wheels")

motorcycle = Motorcycle()
print("Motorcycle has", motorcycle.get_wheels(), "wheels")
```